# TLS Connection Request Failure: Mismatched Server Certificate Name (server_name) During Database Restoration

Tags: database, ssl, database-restore

i'm a newbie please be patient:(
I'm trying to restore a database using a specific script that works perfectly fine and I get this error WARNING: [16:44:51][New-DbaDatabase] Failure | The target principal name is incorrect
Event 36884, Schannel: The certificate received from the remote server does not contain the expected name. It is therefore not possible to determine whether we are connecting to the correct server. The server name we were expecting is svr-mssql. The TLS connection request has failed. The attached data contains the server certificate.

I'm not sure what the problem is... this is happening to new machines we deployed in the lasts 6 months or so, but all other ones the script is working perfectly fine.
Any ideas?

Expecting to restore the database without any issues

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: No, you should be patiently reading the help pages on what you can post here. Hint: if there is no PL or language specific tool mentioned then it is probably off topic.